# Semantic UI Search form is not fetching object data

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I'm pulling a list of countries from an endpoint. I think that I am constructing the object correctly but I am not getting any results in the search form, however with inline declaration of content[] it works fine.

[image: Empty searchbox]

The API JSON response looks like this:

```
{country: "Albania", code: "AL"}
{country: "Algeria", code: "DZ"}
{country: "Andorra", code: "AD"}
{country: "Angola", code: "AO"}
```

```
var content = [];
$.getJSON('/getCountries', function(data){
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        $.each(value, function(key, value){
            if (key == 'country') {
                content.push({ title: value})
            }
        })
    })
})

$('.ui.search')
  .search({
      source: content
  })
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Looks to me like an async issue.

`$(".ui.search").search()` is getting called before `$.getJSON()` has returned with data.

### Let's break down what's happening:

```js
/*
$.getJSON() is shorthand for

$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
})

which is asynchronous.

See https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
*/

// start the ajax call
$.getJSON(

  // URL from which we're fetching JSON data
  "/getCountries", 

  // the "success" callback function to be executed after a successful request
  function (data) {
    parseData(data);
  }
);

// begins executing immediately after .getJSON()
// without waiting for data to return
$('.ui.search').search({
  // content is still empty at this point, since data hasn't come back yet
  source: content
})
```

### Solution

**We need to call `.search()` *after* the async `.getJSON()` call returns with data.**

Since we're already making use of the callback function that executes after we get our JSON data back, let's do all of our `data` stuff inside that callback.

Here I've made two smaller functions: one to parse the data into the form that we want `content` to have, and one to call `.search()` to init the search form with that content.

We can now call those two functions from inside our callback, where we know we've gotten the data.

```js
// set up empty array
var content = [];

// when this is called, use the value of the content array
function populateSearch() {
  $(".ui.search").search({
    source: content
  });
}

// when this is called, push data into the content array
function parseData(data) {
  for (var item of data) {
    content.push({ title: item.country });
  }
}

$.getJSON("/getCountries", function (data) {
  // first parse data into the content array
  parseData(data);

  // then call the function that sets up search
  populateSearch();
});
```

#### Modernized to ES6-level Javascript

You could write it more concisely like so:

```js
function populateSearch(data) {
  // use .map() to transform our data array to a new array in one step
  const content = data.map(item => (
    { title: item.country }
  ));

  // init the search form with our new content array
  $(".ui.search").search({
    source: content
  });
}

$.getJSON("/getCountries", function (data) {
  populateSearch(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify the code a bit using plain javascript:

```js
var content = [];

$.getJSON("/getCountries", function (data) {
  parseData(data);
});

function parseData(data) {
  for (var item of data) {
    content.push({ title: item.country });
  }
}

$(".ui.search").search({
  source: content,
});
```

I used this for the data assuming it's an array of objects:

```js
const data = [
  { country: "Albania", code: "AL" },
  { country: "Algeria", code: "DZ" },
  { country: "Andorra", code: "AD" },
  { country: "Angola", code: "AO" },
];
```

Comment: Thank you @Ron. 

Same issue :/

The data I have provided is in JSON format returned via the /getCountries endpoint